# Tech Gift Ideas For Guests

Tags: tech-industry, gifts

**Situation:** I work at a tech company. Some guests will visit the company. Gifts will be given to the guests.

**Problem:** What are suitable gifts? (apart from clothes, cups and notebooks)

I have come up with the following items based on diversity, functionality and compatibility:

- Multi-purpose Pen
- Wireless Power Bank
- Universal Phone Dock

or should I focus on simple items such as USB flash drive?

**Reference:** sourceec

Thank you very much!

Comment: Who uses USB flash drives these days? Most official computers would not allow external devices and most of the data is transferred by uploading on some cloud platform anyways.

Comment: @PagMax my wife brought home a USB the other day, I couldn't believe it

Comment: What are you using instead? Just curious

Comment: USB's are usually the go to

Comment: We would never use USB memory sticks - they are explicitly banned in many companies...

Answer (score 2):

Going from your options, if I were a guest I would appreciate the phone dock the most. Not all phones support wireless charging and multi-purpose pens might as well be a just pens. I would also consider earphones or earbuds depending on your gift budget.

Comment: earphones are always appreciated